How to sum (SUMIF OR SUMIFS) only when there are consecutively same values?
I have a condition column where some "condition values" are consecutive, which may or may not repeat further down, while some are single "condition values". I need to sum (either using SUMIF or SUMIFS) only those values whose "condition values" are consecutive. For example,



Condition
Values
Sum




A
20
20


A
25
45


B
10
10


B
15
25


B
22
47


C
12
12


D
30
30


D
25
55


D
24
79


A
24
24


A
18
42


A
26
68


D
20
20


D
20
40


B
25
25


B
25
50


B
20
70


C
18
18


C
12
30



Note the sum of A's after D's starts with 0 and adds only the three consecutive A's.

You don't need SUMIF for this, the formula can be defined like this:

If Condition on current row != Condition on the previous row, Sum for this row = Value for this row
Else, Sum for this row = Sum for previous row + Value for this row. This will take care of the "consecutive" aspect.

Assuming the above data starts at A1:
# Cell D2
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,B2+D1)


Use a simple IF condition to check if column A matches the row above.
=IF(A2=A1,C1+B2,B2)



A Running Sum

In MS365, you could do the following:

=LET(cond,A2:A20,vals,B2:B20,
    SCAN(0,MAP(vals,cond=VSTACK("",DROP(cond,-1)),
        LAMBDA(v,c,LAMBDA(x,v+x*c))),
        LAMBDA(x,f,f(x))))


How this works is covered in DjC's answer to the similar question Restarting and resuming a running total for multiple values.

The corresponding running count can also be produced using the SCAN function in the following way:


=LET(cond,A2:A20,
    SCAN(0,VSTACK("",DROP(cond,-1))=cond,
        LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,1))))


